# return all output from a for loop in python 3

Tags: python

I trying to return all results from a loop. the out is just strings of data from basic show commands off cisco devices. Both devices print their output just fine but when i return the for loop I only get the output from the last device in the list.

I have tried a dict list on top of the for loop but the output is string i guess so it does not accept the information.

```
    # Juniper Normalize the data for command line interface
    juniper_command = '"({})"'.format('|'.join(src_a + src_p + dst_a + dst_p))
    # Device IP list
    fw_a = ['10.90.2.20', '10.90.1.10']

    try:
        result = ()
        for ip in fw_a:
            if "true" in str(p_show):
                device = {"device_type": "juniper_junos", "username": username, "host": ip, "password": password}
                connection = netmiko.ConnectHandler(**device)
                connection.find_prompt(delay_factor=2)
                time.sleep(1)
                connection.enable()
                resp = connection.send_command(
                    'show configuration | display xml | match ' + str(juniper_command), delay_factor=2)
                print(ip + '\n' + resp)
                result = resp

        return result
```

My expected results would be to return all data from the devices in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Everytime you run through the loop, you call `result = resp`, which overwrites the value of `result` with `resp`.  So, at the end of the loop, the value of `result` is just the value of `resp` from the last loop.

If you want to get a list of of all of the values of `resp` from each loop iteration, it might make sense to make `result` a list (use `result = []` instead of `result = ()`), and then instead of saying `result = resp`, you could instead say `result.append(resp)`.

Edit:  It looks like you need to return a tuple, so as mentioned in the comment by Hans, you can use `return tuple(result)` or `return tuple(r for r in result)`.

Comment: I have tried that but the output from resp = connection.send_command is just a blob of data from a network device. so i get this errors.

Comment: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.

Comment: `return tuple(result)`

Comment: I have tried return tuple(result) and i get not return back. I have result = [ ] at the top of my for loop and result.append(resp) then i just tried turn tuple(result) i got noting back to my post

Comment: @kbirds30 It is difficult to say exactly why your return value is empty, is any of the code raising an exception?  Are you seeing any output when you call `print(ip + '\n' + resp)`?

Comment: yes the print gives me all the output from the firewalls in the fw_a list. the output from those device is just a string of data in json xml or test.

Comment: i did try return str(result) that gave me the output of the first device in the list but no the send. Note print alway's returns both outputs from the devices and at the end of the loop i see the Post

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help from ChocolateAndChees.
i go this solved with adding result = [] on the top of the loop
then result.append(resp)
then return str(result)